# How to get the positions of the matched points with Brute-Force Matching / SIFT Descriptors

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I tried matching my SIFT-Keypoints with BF-matcher. I used to do it like [this](http://tutorial%20https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html).

But if I want to get the x,y-positions with `print(good)` it only gives me something like this:

`DMatch 000001DD9C4E0EB0`

How can I convert this into positions?

Answer (score 14):

As you provided no code, I answer your question based on the code in the tutorial.
Basically, keypoints are the points detected by the SIFT algorithm with the rotation, scale and x,y position, and descriptors are just the vectors of features used to match them.
In the matches variable you have a set of matches between descriptors (DMatch). Keypoints are located in kp1 and kp2.
To find two points (p1,p2) that are matched use the code like this:

```
for match in matches:
  p1 = kp1[match.queryIdx].pt
  p2 = kp2[match.trainIdx].pt
```

Comment: It is the same code like in the tutorial (Brute-Force Matching with SIFT Descriptors and Ratio Test) but when I add your Code it Shows me "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'queryIdx'"

Comment: @hajo , make sure you are appending 'm' in the matches, and not '[m]'. If you are appending [m], just make ie ```kp1[match[0].queryIdx].pt``` instead.